# LLDB does not appear to be reading my .lldbinit file on startup

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

I have a file ~/.lldbinit with a single alias:

```
command alias pi print (int)
```

But when I run my app from Xcode, the alias does not work.  However, if I manually enter the alias, then the alias does work:

```
(lldb) pi 6
error: 'pi' is not a valid command.
(lldb) command alias pi print (int)
(lldb) pi 6
(int) $3 = 6
(lldb)
```

This leads me to suspect that my .lldbinit file is not getting read.  Or is there a different problem that I am missing?  Can anyone help?

Comment: For me, not only is Xcode 4.6 ignoring this file, but also running lldb from the command line (as `lldb` or `xcrun lldb`) ignores it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that ~/.lldbinit does work in Xcode 4.3.2, iOS.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem. It turned out, that I had a syntax error in my .lldbinit file which leads to lldb silently ignoring the file. You can try manually loading the file with

```
command source ~/.lldbinit
```

which will show syntax errors.

Answer (score 9):

Make the file executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.lldbinit
```

Answer (score 4):

I created a .llbdbinit file just like you and reproduced your problem in my copy of Xcode 4.1.  I can't get aliases to work either.

Since ~/.lldbinit [is documented by Apple](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-69/docs/lldb-for-gdb-users.txt) as supposedly being read when started up, I suspect that lldbinit file reading is currently busted in shipping versions of Xcode 4.  Not sure what pre-release versions are doing, but I'd recommend filing a bug at bugreporter.apple.com.

p.s.

One thing I noticed on one blog ([here; look in the "differences between OSX & iOS" section](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/3/21/compiler-options-in-xcode-gcc-or-llvm.html)) is that lldb only works for MacOS and *NOT* for iOS, at least as of a bunch of months ago.

Comment: lldb does work for me in iOS apps.  In many ways it is worse than GDB, but it has two big things going for it:  1.  The "step into" button is reliable [in GDB it often steps over instead] and 2.  Apple appears to want to make it the debugger of the future.  I imagine they will keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to get [this plugin](https://github.com/ryanolsonk/LLDB-QuickLook) to work.

```
command script import ~/Documents/002.ME/001.BITBUCKET_REPO/xcode_plugin_lldb_quicklook/GITHUB-LLDB-QuickLook/LLDB-QuickLook/lldb_quick_look.py
command alias ql quicklook
```

The path to the py file was wrong so kept reporting the error:

**`error: 'ql' is not a valid command.`**

Once I fixed it. I had to restart Xcode 5 and it worked.

I didn't have to restart Mac.

I didn't have to make the file executable.

Answer (score 0):

if you created the lldbinit file with some editor then it might have screwed it.
try openning the lldbinit file with vi and check if it just plain text