# Error creating LLDB target at path, Xcode 6 GM seed

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, iphone-6

I'm getting this error whenever I build in Xcode 6 GM Seed. It seems to be making my app insanely slow. What exactly does this mean and how do I fix it?

I had the following error:

> Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '.....'- using an empty
>   LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.

**PS**: im not able to run my app, its stuck on the splash screen

Comment: Have you seen [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088252/xcode-error-creating-lldb-target)? That solved the very exact problem for me.

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, but you can probably get past the splash screen by clicking the Continue button in the Debug Console.

Answer (score 2):

There is a thread in the Apple Developer Forum, https://devforums.apple.com/message/1010068#1010068 that describes how to diagnose this issue. I had his issue for Xcode 6 GM Seed, specifically - Version 6.0.1 (6A317). This isn't necessarily a solution, but it may help some people get a better diagnosis

Useful steps are as follows -

1) Create or modify your `~/.lldbinit` and add `log enable -f /tmp/lldb-api.txt lldb api` to it.

2) Rerun your debugger session (no need to restart Xcode or anything)

3) Inspect the file at `/tmp/lldb-api.txt`. Look for a line beginning with `SBDebugger::CreateTarget(...)`. Mine looked something like this

> SBDebugger(0x7f83671fd600)::CreateTarget
>   (filename="/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dino-gjuxikhuyokkqufeqmesmgjcxylu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dino.app",
>   triple=x86_64, platform_name=(null), add_dependent_modules=1,
>   error=the specified architecture 'x86_64' is not compatible with
>   'i386-apple-ios' in
>   '/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dino-gjuxikhuyokkqufeqmesmgjcxylu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dino.app/Dino')
>   => SBTarget(0x0)

4) Inspect the target file from the above log output, in my case -

> file
>   "/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dino-gjuxikhuyokkqufeqmesmgjcxylu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dino.app/Dino"
>
> /Users/apanagar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dino-gjuxikhuyokkqufeqmesmgjcxylu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dino.app/Dino:
>   Mach-O executable i386

5) So, In my case my problem was the architectures I was building for. The target architecture for your project should match the one on the SBDebugger::CreateTarget() line in the log output.

Xcode doc's point out the following. I had to go through my nested frameworks and change some outdated architecture targets -

> NOTE ABOUT 64-BIT ARCHITECTURE
>
> An app extension target must include the arm64 architecture in its
>   Architectures build settings or it will be rejected by the App Store.
>   Xcode includes this architecture with its “Standard architectures”
>   setting when you create a new app extension target.
>
> If your containing app target links to an embedded framework, the app
>   must also include the arm64 architecture or it will be rejected by the
>   App Store.
>
> For more information about 64-bit development, see 64-Bit Transition
>   Guide for Cocoa Touch or 64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa, depending
>   on your target platform.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov There seem to be some ongoing issues with it that are related to specific versions of the toolchain. Did you try some of the suggestions in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689735/lldb-does-not-appear-to-be-reading-my-lldbinit-file-on-startup

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help in your case. But I tried this solution and it worked pretty neatly for me.
Pull up the terminal and type - **rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**

This is supposed to remove the huge stack of DerivedData folder and make the app execute faster.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Architectures=$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and run your app on a 64 bit device? (iPhone 5S or iPhone 5S simulator)

Apple seems to be stricter with apps which don't support 64bit. So if there is no specific reason, I think it's better to include arm64 in your build architecture

> NOTE ABOUT 64-BIT ARCHITECTURE
>
> An app extension target must include the arm64 architecture in its
>   Architectures build settings or it will be rejected by the App Store.
>   Xcode includes this architecture with its “Standard architectures”
>   setting when you create a new app extension target.
>
> If your containing app target links to an embedded framework, the app
>   must also include the arm64 architecture or it will be rejected by the
>   App Store.
>
> For more information about 64-bit development, see 64-Bit Transition
>   Guide for Cocoa Touch or 64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa, depending
>   on your target platform.

Source: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 0):

This warning is solved by changing Build Settings :

1. Select Project -> Build Settings
2. Change **'Architectures' to 'Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)'**
   [image: Step 2]
3. This will prompt an alert stating iOS 5.1.1 and above are supported. Click **'Change Deployment Target to 5.1.1'**

[image: Step 3]

4. Repeat steps for Target (if not changed automatically)

[image: Step 4]

Also, this is preferred build setting since Apple is forcing developers to build apps on 64 but architecture. [Apple document Link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b)

Answer (score 0):

The past *"Error creating LLDB target at path … - using an empty LLDB target"* issue related to Apple's architecture transition from 32-bit to 64-bit resurfaced with the `x86_64` to `arm64` transition.

The following settings resolved the `…using an empty LLDB target…` error for Xcode 15.2 and the associated iPhone Simulator:

Use `file` to check the archicture of the build executable. The build folder can be located with the **Product** > **Show Build Folder in Finder** menu.

```bash
pwd
# …path/to/Build
cd Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExampleName.app

file ExampleName
# Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

### x86_64 can raise the empty LLDB target error when debugging
### iOS in the Simulator on an Apple Silicon computer.
```

*.xcodeproj Settings*

| Title | Name | Debug | Release |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Architectures | `ARCHS` | default: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` | default: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` |
| Excluded Architectures | `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` | unset | unset |
| Build Active Architectures Only | `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` | Yes | default: No |

*CocoaPods Podfile*

```rb
### other: `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` = YES only for `*Debug*` configurations
if config.name.include?("Debug")
    config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
end
```

*debug.xcconfig*

As FYI, the `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` setting can be added to `*.xcconfig` files for both implementation and documentation purposes.

```ini
// Resolve "Error creating LLDB target … using an empty LLDB target…"
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
```