# Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path""

Tags: xcode, ios8

I'm getting this error whenever I build in Xcode 6.1.

**Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/cepl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DNIMobileDNIAppIpad-fjstlqjfyowzavgznbxqxcvaigte/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DNIApp.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.**

I tried all given solution in 
both links : 1. [Xcode - Error creating LLDB target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088252/xcode-error-creating-lldb-target/27104984#27104984). 2. [Error creating LLDB target at path, Xcode 6 GM seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761447/error-creating-lldb-target-at-path-xcode-6-gm-seed).
but problem is same.
can anyone help me out?

Comment: My problem got solved. I tried all the solutions mentioned above but the problem was same. So I uninstalled the xcode and installed it again and the problem got resolved.I think whenever xcode was trying to load the application connection was getting lost.