# Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, ios-simulator

when I run the Application in the Simulator Xcode show me this warning and I have to kill iPhone Simulator whenever I run Application.

The Library that give me this warning is 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils': if I remove this pod the warning disappear.

> ```
> Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path
> '/Users/francescobeccu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-ctqolwhwcynkwqepnfcbrevvreau/Build/Products/DebugUAT-iphonesimulator/MyApplication.app'-
> using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from
> remote devices.
> ```

I tried all given solution:
[Xcode - Error creating LLDB target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088252/xcode-error-creating-lldb-target/27104984#27104984),
[Error creating LLDB target at path, Xcode 6 GM seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761447/error-creating-lldb-target-at-path-xcode-6-gm-seed),
[Xcode building for iOS Simulator, but linking in an object file built for iOS, for architecture 'arm64'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-ios-f?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top)
but problem is same. can anyone help me out?

**Environment details**

- Xcode 14.3 - Mac M1 OSX Ventura
- Library versión 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', '4.1.0'
- Cocoapods versión 1.12.1

**Steps to reproduce**

Run Application in the Simulator

**Podfile**

```
pod 'GoogleUtilities' , '7.11.1'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', '4.1.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps' , '7.4.0'
```

**Sample Project**

https://github.com/wesoo/SwiftUI-Maps/

Please take into consideration that my own project is more complex with more Pods then this one.

Comment: What application to run to reproduce this?

Comment: I uploaded this sample project to GitHub. Please take into consideration that my own project is more complex with more Pods then this one: https://github.com/wesoo/SwiftUI-Maps/

Answer (score 0):

Updating 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' to 4.2.2 versión solves the problem.